# My CSS works when my div is in one location, but not when I move it to the header

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a div to the header for special notices - like office closings. The css doesn't work in the header, but if I move the whole div down to the main body section, it works. I moved it just to try and trouble shoot the situation.

```css
#Notice p{
 font-family:'Open Sans';
 color:#d7972a;
 font-size:15px;
 line-height:32px;
}
```

```html
</head>

<body>
 <header>

  <div class="container">

    <div id="mobileNav">
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
    </div>
     <div class="Notice">
      <p> The Office will be closed from 4/1/16 - 4/5/16</p>
     </div>


   <a id="lablogo" href="index.html"> <img src="images/AmpLabLogo.png" alt="Andrews Amp Lab Logo"></a>
   
  </div> 
   

  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li id="dropAbout" class="mobileDropAbout"><a href="#">About<span class="caret"></span></a>
     <ul id="drop2" class="mobileDrop2">
      <li><a href="experience.html">The Andrews Amp Lab Experience</a></li>
      <li><a href="bio.html">Bio</a></li>
      <li><a href="clients.html">Clients</a></li>
      <li><a href="pricing.html">Pricing</a></li>
      <li><a href="warranty.html">Warranty</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="dropService" class="mobileDropService"><a href="#">Services<span class="caret"></span></a>

     <ul id="drop" class="mobileDrop"> 
      <li><a href="Tone_Resurrection.html">Tone Resurrection</a></li>
      <li><a href="Repairs.html">Repairs</a></li>
      <li><a href="Cap.html">Cap Job</a></li>
      <li><a href="Modifications.html">Modifications</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="gallery home.html">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="Testimonials.html">Testimonials</a></li>
    <li><a href="Tube_Reviews_for_Guitarists.html">Tube Reviews</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
  
 </header>
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the selector: Notice is a class not an id, so just change the selector to `.Notice p`

Comment: Thanks! I'm blind.